# Unix search and replace using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a firewall log which has time stamp in the format of `date +%d/%B/%Y`.

```
$ date +%d/%B/%Y

21/May/2018
```

Log Line ( Input )  :

```
#cat firewall.log 

1.5.5.1 - - [20/May/2018:00:00:00 +0000] "GET blah.com HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 299 262 293 227 0
```

I understood how to change the time format using `sed` every day .

```
sed "s/\[20\/May\/2018/\[21\/May\/2018/g" firewall.log
```

I would like to change to latest timestamp regularly on the log with unix date module

```
$date +%d/%B/%Y
21/May/2018
```

I got how to get the previous date as well

```
$ date -d '-1 day' '+%d/%B/%Y'
20/May/2018
```

How to match the previous day's date from the log and replace with latest day's date stamp using ( 21/May/2018 ) `sed` ?

Expected Output :

```
$sed "s/previous_day_match/latest_day_match/g" firewall.log


1.5.5.1 - - [21/May/2018:00:00:00 +0000] "GET blah.com HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 299 262 293 227 0
```

Comment: It will be better if you could post samples of input and expected output too in your post with CODE TAGS.

Comment: why would you want to change a log :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, should work:

```
sed 's!'$(date -d '-1 day' '+%d/%B/%Y')'!'$(date +%d/%B/%Y)'!g' firewall.log
```

and you can add `-i` flag to overwrite the logs, e.i., `sed -i ...`